# Конвертер единиц измерения веса на JS

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Нужно создать конвертер между единицами измерения веса. Даны такие единицы: кг, г, т
Конвертер должен поддерживать конвертацию между любыми единицами. Данный конвертер нужно сделать только с помощью JS и JSON.
Во входящих параметрах есть объект:

```js
{"weight": {"unit": "kg", "value": 2}, "convert_to": "g"}
```

А на выходе должно быть:

```js
{"unit": "g", "value": 2000}
```

Как можно реализовать данный конвертер? Буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: "Как можно реализовать данный конвертер?"  что значит как? ну например функцией

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const obj = { "weight": { "unit": "kg", "value": 2 }, "convert_to": "g" };  

// Единицы измерения: ton, kg, g
// Индекс каждого, через (str.length)

const convertTo = (obj) => {
  // Индекс входящих данных
  const countIn = obj.weight.unit.length;
  // Индекс выходящих данных
  const countOut = obj.convert_to.length;
  // Значение (степень увеличения/уменьшения 1 или 2)
  // Зависит от того (что во что конвертируется)
  let count;
  let unit;
  let value;
  if (countIn > countOut) {
    count = countIn - countOut;
    value = obj.weight.value * Math.pow(1000, count);
    unit = obj.convert_to;
  } else if (countIn < countOut) {
    count = countOut - countIn;
    console.log(count);
    value = obj.weight.value / Math.pow(1000, count);
    unit = obj.convert_to;
  } else {
    value = obj.weight.value;
    unit = obj.convert_to;
  }

  const result = { unit, value };
  return result
}

console.log(convertTo(obj));
```